# How developers make profit from their decentralized coins

Tags: tokens

I understand how centralized token/coin developers are making profit, they literally own big part of total supply, but how's about fully decentralized token/coins?

Are they saving some tokens before launching it? or they still have some kind of access to total supply?

And how they patching it? for example Bitcoin, if it's already online, supply is fixed and its fully decentralized, how developers still making changes in it's core?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on the project and how it is set up. I would encourage you to take a look at the token-economics of [UNI for example](https://uniswap.org/blog/uni/).

Usually most teams keep a good amount of tokens that are vested. So they belong to the team but they only become available to them after 1-2 or 3 years in the future. The more the team works and improves the protocol, the higher the chance that the tokens they hold become valuable and thus they can cash out in the future.

There are some protocols that have inflation built in, meaning that they produce tokens as they go along and provide them for either current token holders, miners or other contributors. Every protocol has its own design.

When Bitcoin has a new version ready, all miners should patch their software to the latest version so they can mine and earn rewards. If they do not disagree, a fork happens. For Bitcoin for example, [there have been a few of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bitcoin_forks)